# Origin of $V_a$ (median) notation

Tags: terminology, notation, geometry

My question about median of a triangle.

The English equivalent of the Turkish word "kenarortay" is "median". In English-language geometry sources (like books or web pages), the length of the median is often denoted with expressions like $m_a$. On the other hand, the notation $V_a$ is also common in Turkish textbooks. We don't use $K_a$. This might be due to Turkish mathematicians learning geometry from other mathematicians who speak languages other than English. For instance, we know that German scientists came to Turkey in the $1930$s. However, I'm not sure if this notation was used by the Germans. Do you have any information about the origin of the $V_a$ notation?

Of course, mathematical notations can develop independently in local education systems or at a particular university or school. Do you know of any other countries that use the $V_a$ notation?

Thanks for your interest!

**Notes:**

Some examples

**1.** In wikipedia Median (geometry) page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry) we see that $m_a$ notation like $m_a = \sqrt{\dfrac{2b^2 + 2c^2 - a^2}{4}}$.

**2.** In Mark Dabbs' *Elementary Triangle Geometry* book, we can see $m_A,m_B,m_C$ notations
[image]

Comment: The origin of the use of $V$ does not seem to be German, because the median is called *Seitenhalbierende* ("that which cuts the side in half"), so the length of medians is commonly denoted by $s_{a}$, $s_{b}$, $\ldots$. An older German term for the median is *Schwerelinie* ("gravity line", compare: centroid = center of gravity = *Schwerpunkt*; its length likewise denoted by $s_{a}$, etc.), which is cognate with the Dutch term for median, *zwaartelijn*, whose length is usually denoted by $z_{a}$, $z_{b}$, $\ldots$.